# Regex search in a text editor to look for entries

Tags: sql, regex, textwrangler

I am looking for a regular expression to remove comment lines from a sql fine.  All of the comments start with "COMMENT ON" (obviously) but may tend to have more than one line.  I was able to come up with an expression to remove a single line but am struggling with multiple lines.  A typical entry I am looking to remove looks like this:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE account_heading IS $$
This table holds the account headings in the system.  Each account must belong 
to a heading, and a heading can belong to another heading.  In this way it is 
possible to nest accounts for reporting purposes.$$;
```

So what I need is a regular expression that follows multiple lines up to the point it sees a 
semicolon.

I came up with this one that will search to the second line and stop at the double dollar ($$).  I just started with RegEx yesterday so forgive me if this is absolutely completely wrong (which I am sure it is):

```
^COMMENT ([^\n\r]+)[\n\r]([\$;\n\r]+)
```

I am doing this in TextWrangler with the Grep option on a Mac.

Thanks!

Comment: If you need help, people will help. If you need code, write code. Maybe post your one-line regex

Comment: Added it.  Thanks for the tip.  Not trying to have people do it for me, its just that I have been at this for a while and regex seems like it takes some time to learn.  Just trying to know when I might be in over my head for a given task.

Comment: And SO is perfect for that. Just trying to help you avoid the haters :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know SQL very well, but if you want the content between the '$$', just use:

```
\${2}[^\${2}]*\${2};
```

If you want everything after the 'IS' Word:

```
COMMENT .*? IS ([^;]*)
```

Matches anything that isn't a semicolon (get the first group, not the match).

Comment: That did it for many of them!  Thanks!  It actually got up to the $$ and not the semicolon.  So I threw a semicolon at the end and it grabbed the whole thing.

Comment: Any idea why it would ignore some of the entries?  Could it be the type of line break?  Unfortunately commenting here removes the formatting of the lines if I try to add them.

Comment: Ah, it was a spacing issue.  I removed the space after IS and made it "COMMENT .*? IS([^;]*);" and it got the rest!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like `COMMENT\sON.*?\$\$;` - it should work if you are able to set your editor to match on multiple lines (usually by specifying the `s` flag).

Comment: It must be my editor.  It did not find any results.  Thanks for the attempt. :)